# Find the kth PCA component by substract the k-1 first components

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to understand the PCA algorithm. I read that once I subtract the first component from the data, and then execute the algorithm again. The first PC I'll get in the second round is equivalent to the PC2 from the first PCA.

Source for that is in [Link1- Eq 7.11](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=NUikAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA201#v=onepage&q&f=false), but it appears in many other places.

I can't replicate the property in R,

```
#Scale the data 
USArrests.1 <- scale(USArrests[,-3]) 
# Running the first PCA algorithm
pca.1 <- prcomp(USArrests.1, scale = TRUE) 

#Substract the first component from the data
USArrests.2<-USArrests.1-(pca.1$rotation[,1])^2*USArrests.1 

#Running the second PCA
pca.2 <- prcomp(USArrests.2, scale = TRUE)

#Comparing the rotation
pca.1
pca.2
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For prcom, the principal component is implemented via SVD, where the matrix $X$ can be decomposed into:

$\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{W}^T $

where $\mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is the principal component score and $\mathbf{W}^T$ is the transpose of your eigenvectors, or transpose of your loadings as returned by the `prcomp()` function.

So to subtract the first principal component out, you need to multiply the principal component by the transpose of the loadings and then subtract it from your original values In the example below,

```
USArrests.2 = USArrests.1 -  pca.1$x[,1,drop=FALSE] %*% t(pca.1$rotation[,1])

head(cbind(prcomp(USArrests.2)$x[,1],pca.1$x[,2]))
                 [,1]       [,2]
Alabama    -0.8338118  0.8338118
Alaska      1.5239622 -1.5239622
Arizona     0.4983038 -0.4983038
Arkansas   -0.3247326  0.3247326
California  1.2725770 -1.2725770
Colorado    1.4264063 -1.4264063
```

The directionality is flipped but you get back the components.